# I have a class I want some method transfer to an array's object

Tags: ios, objective-c, message-forwarding

Like the title said: I have a ObjcClass
I want some thing can be reused ，
because the class may have
`-(void)test1:xxx  -(void)test2:xxx argu:yyy`
I don't want to do that

```
[dispatchArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
      [obj test2:xxx argu:yyy];
 }];
```

example:

```
 - (void)test:(NSString *)argument1 {
    NSArray *dispatchArray = @[];//If the array is initialized with multiple objects
//I want each object to call the "test:" method unlike the following
//    [dispatchArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
//        [obj performSelector:@selector(test:) withObject:argument1];
//        // or [obj test:argument1];
//    }];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [_services enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * stop) {
        if ([obj respondsToSelector:_cmd]) {
            [obj application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
        }
    }];

    return YES;
}
```

like this ，UIApplicationDelegate has a number of method ，I don't want write  **[obj application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];** or **[obj applicationWillResignActive:application];** at every method,On the contrary I hope that method like **[obj respondsToSelector:_cmd]** ，that I can propose as a general method like **[obj invokeWithMethod:_cmd arguments:_VA_LIST];**
[Whether these methods can be optimized,because they do the same thing to different method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9S8jw.png)

Comment: Where are the extra arguments coming from, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods you app delegate has been implemented, you should implement as before. To the method in `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol which your app delegate did not implement, you can use message forwarding to achieve your target. Override the message forwarding methods of your app delegate as below:

```
- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    struct objc_method_description desc = protocol_getMethodDescription(objc_getProtocol("UIApplicationDelegate"), aSelector, NO, YES);
    if (desc.name != nil) {
        return YES;
    }
    return [super respondsToSelector:aSelector];
}

- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation {
    SEL selector = [anInvocation selector];
    struct objc_method_description desc = protocol_getMethodDescription(objc_getProtocol("UIApplicationDelegate"), selector, NO, YES);
    if (desc.name != nil) {
        [_services enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
            if ([obj respondsToSelector:selector]) {
                [anInvocation invokeWithTarget:obj];
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Get the return values:

```
NSMutableArray *returnValues = [NSMutableArray array];
[_services enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    id returnValue = [NSNull null];
    if ([obj respondsToSelector:selector]) {
        [anInvocation invokeWithTarget:obj];

        const char *returnType = anInvocation.methodSignature.methodReturnType;

        if( !strcmp(returnType, @encode(void)) ){
            //If the return value is `void`, just set returnValue = [NSNull null]
        } else if( !strcmp(returnType, @encode(id)) ){
            // if the return type is derived data types(`id`)
            [anInvocation getReturnValue:&returnValue];
        }else{
            //if the return value is basicdata type
            NSUInteger length = [anInvocation.methodSignature methodReturnLength];
            void *buffer = (void *)malloc(length);
            [anInvocation getReturnValue:buffer];
            if( !strcmp(returnType, @encode(BOOL)) ) {
                returnValue = [NSNumber numberWithBool:*((BOOL*)buffer)];  
            } else if( !strcmp(returnType, @encode(NSInteger)) ){
                returnValue = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:*((NSInteger*)buffer)];  
            }  
            returnValue = [NSValue valueWithBytes:buffer objCType:returnType];
        }
    }
    // If the `obj` can not responds to selector, or the return value is void(nil), we set the `returnValue = [NSNull null]`
    [returnValues addObject:returnValue];
}]
```

Comment: I konw this method，but this is not the answer I want，Maybe I don't describe it well。I have update the question ，I just want a general method do that。

Comment: I just want a dispatcher ,when calling a dispatcher method, the dispatcher call the method for each object in an array, I don't want to repeat the same logic at every dispatcher's implemented method,Sorry。

Comment: You can create a category of NSArray.

Comment: [Example image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9S8jw.png) Whether these methods can be optimized,because they do the same thing to different method

Comment: This is just what I wanted, Thank you so much.

Comment: I have another question，if the anInvocation have a return value，after testing I found that the return value is the last object invoke returned value，that's why ?

Comment: Get the return value just behind this(`[anInvocation invokeWithTarget:obj];`) line?

Comment: yeah,when the last obj invoke.

Comment: You should get the return value every time you call the code `[anInvocation invokeWithTarget:obj];`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just want to loop through the objects in the array.  This is not very Type safe. All objects must provide a "test" method.  If they're all the same Class that would be better than using NSObject.

```
for (NSObject *obj in dispatchArray) {
        [obj performSelector:@selector(test:) withObject:argument1];
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question, This is not the answer I want，Maybe I don't describe it well。Thank you anyway。